# Function return value undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return

I have this function:

```
function addressVerification() {

  var del;

  let addVer = $('#add_verified').val();
  let maddVer = $('#madd_verified').val();

  if (addVer == "yes" && maddVer == "yes") {
      del = true;
  } else {
      del = false;
  }
  return del;
}
```

When I call it:

```
$('#add_verified').change(function(){
  var ver = addressVerification();
  console.info("This is the returned value from the verified address function: "+ ver);
});
```

It comes back as "undefined."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest that your lack of good indentation is the key here.  You have too many closing braces (`}`)

Comment: Extra closing brace needs to be removed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had an additional if statement I took out and forgot to take out the other bracket. It's still not working. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error

```
function addressVerification() {
    var del;
    let addVer = $('#add_verified').val();
    let maddVer = $('#madd_verified').val();

    if (addVer == "yes" && maddVer == "yes") {
        del = true;
    } else {
        del = false;
    }
  } . <----- This is closing the function, ant thus, returning undefined
  return del;
}
```

Comment: I did that. The returned value is still undefined.

Comment: Did you clear your cache? I just tested it in my console, and I get false

Comment: Yup. If I put a value on the var when I declare it.. then it will return that value. But it's like the value is being returned asynchronously before the if statement has a chance to run and I don't know how to fix that. 

For instance, just to test it, I declared my var del = "pollywog", then the if statement with values of "yes" and "no" instead of "true/false" and it returned "pollywog."

Comment: @MechanicalFlamingo Made some changes to the code and it works now. Check it out. https://jsfiddle.net/u0djf2vh/

Comment: So... after screwing around with it some more I discovered that I needed to update my variable after the conditions were met and before any additional actions and/or if statements.

Now it's finally working!!!

Thank you to all of you!